# Need help with a double integral

Tags: definite-integrals

$$
\int_0^{1} \int_0^{\sqrt{1+x^2}} \frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2 + y^2}}\, dy dx
$$

The question need to be solved using double integrals concept.
I think the curve is rectangular hyperbola.

Answer (score 0):

The region of integration is the portion of the unit circle lying in the first quadrant. Now convert into polar form. Then your integral is 
$\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\int_{0}^{1}(1/r)rdrd\theta=\int_{0}^{\pi/2}(\int_{0}^{1}dr)d\theta=\pi/2.$

Comment: $$
\int_0^{1} \int_0^{\sqrt{1+x^2}} \frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2 + y^2}}\, dy dx
$$           I have edited the question.Please try now